# Laser LA03-5000 wiring to RAMPS 1.4

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, laser, cnc

I'm totally lost. I have been searching about two days how to correctly wire Blue Laser LA03-5000 to RAMPS 1.4 board.

This laser has 12 V input and separates PWM/TTL wires. I have found out how to control laser with no PWM (just hook it to D9 same as a fan), but how do I correctly wire this type of laser? I really want to wire it correctly for safety reasons.

[image: Blue Laser LA03-5000]

Answer (score 1):

Please look into [this question](/q/9970/), this is a very similar question and also involves PWM and a RAMPS 1.4 shield.

In your case you connect the top red wire on the right bottom connector to the D4 pin and adjust the firmware accordingly as described in [this answer](/a/9972/).

The bottom 2 wires of the lower right connector should be connected to ground and 12 V (resp. black and red).

[image: Wiring of laser power control module]